# ¿Como puedo conservar una fuente de texto en un proyecto de Windows Forms, C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buen día, queria saber si es posible poder conservar una fuente dentro del proyecto de Windows Forms en c#, ya que es un trabajo escolar, y las fuentes que yo tengo obviamente no se conservaran si la PC en la que se ejecuta el programa no cuenta con las fuentes.
¿Existe la posibilidad de conservar la fuente de texto?

Comment: Si, tenes que mandarlas con tu instalador del programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las fuentes que se utilizan en windows suelen ser del tipo True Type (con la extensión .ttf) y suelen estar registradas en el sistema y almacenadas en c:\Windows\Fonts.
Al distribuir un programa que utilice una fuente no estandar, es necesario incluir el/los archivos .ttf en el instalador, que a su vez las registrará en el sistema de destino durante la instalación, permitiendo que el programa (y otros) la puedan utilizar.